# I can't access custom React Component in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to use my custom component but its not appearing. What I am doing wrong?

Custom Component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class cardComp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>My Custom Component</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default cardComp
```

and the class where I am trying to use it

```
import React from 'react'

import { cardComp } from 'src/components/cardComp'

const Daily = () => {
    // console.log(kpiData)

 return (
        <>


           <div><cardComp /></div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Daily
```

Also, it says cardComp is declared but never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you added a bracket. Please remove that and try like this:

```
import cardComp from 'src/components/cardComp';
```

Also, I would like to suggest first letter is better capitalized for the component.

For instance CardComp instead of cardComp.

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase elements in JSX are considered native HTML elements. You must use uppercase names for your custom components.

```js
export class CardComp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>My Custom Component</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```js
import { CardComp } from 'src/components/cardComp';
```

Furthermore, look into using function components instead of the older class components.